# find the modification time and modifed user name of a file linux

Tags: linux, unix, stat

I am using Linux Environment and read-write permission was provided to a file. Is there any command to find the modification time and the user who modified the file in linux command. Read write permission was provided to a

```
stat <filename>
```

will display the access and modification time of the file not the one who modified the file.

Answer (score 1):

Linux and POSIX filesystems don't keep the metadata information about who modified last an existing file.

A file does have an owner id, often the user id of the process which created that file.

If the file is some kind of source code, you'll better put it under some version control system (VCS); I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/). Then the VCS is managing such metadata so is keeping the information about who committed last that file.